# Calculus Integration problem Help

Tags: calculus

I am totally stuck at this problem, I have totally no clue where to start:
$$\int x(a^2-x^2)dx$$
I don't know what I should do with the extra variable $a$.  Is this multivariable calculus?  why would it be on a textbook of single variable calculus?  Thanks!

Comment: You can think of it as integrating $f(x) = x(a^2 - x^2)$. Since $a$ is a constant, it doesn't need to be an input to $f$. And since $f$ has just one input, it's a regular, single-variable function.

Answer (score 4):

The $a$ is just an arbitrary constant. You can treat it just as you would any number.

So, in order to compute $\int x(a^2-x^2)dx$, just expand it to $\int (a^2x + x^3)dx$ and use the power rule.

This would still be considered single variable calculus because the $a$ is a constant, not a variable: while we don't care what it is, it still stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think that $a$ is just a contant, and you just need to try it like a number. Then the solution is:

$$\int x(a^2-x^2)dx=\int a^2xdx -\int x^3dx=a^2\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}+C$$

Where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Comment: @The Chaz, Thanks :)